# CentOS 6でなくなったslapd.confに直接書き込み/etc/openldap/slapd.d/ への移行方法

Tags: centos, ldap, openldap

CentOS 6.6の環境でOpenLDAPの設定をしております。
CentOS 6では `slapd.conf` はなくなったということで、
下記のサイトを参考に設定を進めております。

`slapd.conf`にいったん設定を記述し、`slaptest` を使用して移行しようとしたのですが、
`slaptest`コマンドを実行する際、下記のエラーがでてしまいます。

```
[root@mailsvr-01 slapd.d]# slaptest -f /etc/openldap/slapd.conf.obsolete -F /etc/openldap/slapd.d
56724623 /etc/openldap/schema/postfix.schema: line 9 attributetype: Inconsistent duplicate attributeType: "mailRoutingAddress"
slaptest: bad configuration directory!
```

どこをし修正すればいいのか教えていただけますでしょうか。

なお、OpenLDAPを設定して、ゆくゆくはメールアカウントの管理をLDAPで行いたいと考えております。

以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mailRoutingAddress は /etc/openldap/schema/misc.schema にも定義されているので、
重複している(かつ OID が違う)というエラーだと思います。

Comment: @Taichiさん

ありがとうございます。/etc/openldap/schema/postfix.schemaのmailRoutingAddressの行をコメントアウトしたらうまくslap.dディレクトリ配下に反映が行われたのですが、これはこれでコメントアウトしてもよかったのでしょうか。お手数ですが、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: LDAPサーバーに格納する LDAP DIT に `misc.schema` に定義されているオブジェクトクラスを用いないのであれば、問題ありません。